# Direct dynamic JSON feed to Tableau?

Tags: json, dynamic, tableau-api

I have some simple questions:

Does Tableau support direct dynamic JSON feed to refresh the report?

For example if I have a report - orders placed in last 7 days. Everyday I want to see the bar chart refresh with latest orders data in it of last 7 days.

1. Do I have to go through extract API?
2. If yes does Tableau not take direct JSON and I need to write and schedule code to create dynamic TDE file?
3. Can I get a link to sample code that shows "appending" to a TDE file instead of recreating it?

Thanks

Comment: Tableau supports direct connections to a JSON file. Sounds like you are looking to connect to a feed instead of a file. For that, you can write a web data connector.

Comment: Thanks Sam.l You are right, I think I need to look into web data connector implementation. I will search online also but if you can suggest a good link that has practical code to create a web data connector I will appreciate that.